# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/google-chrome unexpectedly exited with ChromeDriver Selenium Python on Linux

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/google-chrome')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

I receive this error:

```
 File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/bin/google-chrome')
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/google-chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

I tried other solutions from the internet but every solution I tried I received a new error. I just want to get page source using python selenium and chrome driver, I don't know why none solutions working for me, any help?

Im do this in client-server, in my local im using windows and its work good, however its different code...

Comment: `executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/google-chrome'` should be the path to chrome driver not chrome.
You can get chrome driver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads for your Chrome version.

Comment: i did this but still not working, now i have this error: Unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Comment: Did you match your Chrome version and Chromedriver version? This may help https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4961

Comment: yes @TekNath    ............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/google-chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Seems you were pretty close. Through the *Key* **`executable_path`** instead of the *absolute path* of `google-chrome` binary you need to pass the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* as the *Value*. So effectively, you need to replace the line of code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/google-chrome')
```

With:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this packages and try again  :

```
apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0=2.50.3-2 \
    libnss3=2:3.26.2-1.1+deb9u1 \
    libgconf-2-4=3.2.6-4+b1 \
    libfontconfig1=2.11.0-6.7+b1
```

or you can install chromium-browser:

```
sudo apt-get install -y chromium-browser
```

Comment: im not sudo user on this server, this is the server from my client

Comment: can't install any package?